# How do I make bone drivers work?

Tags: bones, drivers

I want to bend this character's arm bend, so I use some bones. But of course, there are always deformations. Well, apparently bone drivers are the answer.
But when I go and look at tutorials on it burns my brain cells very quickly.
If there is an alternative that works as good or better and is easier please tell me
[image: this is what I have.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are alternatives, such as the [x-muscle-system](https://blendermarket.com/products/x-muscle-system), but you have to accept that rigging is a technical skill, so my advice is to let those brain cells burn, and ask here what *exactly* you don't understand.

Note that in 2.78 drivers [were improved](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/Animation#Eyedropper_for_Faster_Driver_Setup), but this means that older tutorials became a bit confusing.

Another alternative is to create only thin, skinny characters because they usually deform acceptably with correct weight painting, and the drivers are not needed.